# Prove that in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $[a]^{-1} = [a]$ if and only if $[a]=[1]$ or $[a]=[p-1]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and a an integer. Prove that in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $[a]^{-1} = [a]$ if and only if $[a]=[1]$ or $[a]=[p-1]$.

I greatly appreciate your help on this question!

Comment: I guess $[a] \neq [0]$, right?

Comment: The question does not specify, it simply says a an integer which confuses me.

Comment: If $[a] = [0]$, then $[a]^{-1}$ does not exist. So you need $[a] \neq [0]$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $[a]^{-1} = [a] \iff 1 = [a]^2 \iff [a]^2 - 1 = 0 \iff ([a] - 1)([a] + 1) = 0$.